# Add DNS entry to local /etc/hosts for traffic redirect to PKS Ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, localhost, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kube-dns

My Kubernetes cluster is running in Vmware PKS.

I am having **Ingress** resource with **spec.rules.host: test.domain.com** for backend service "test-service". I understand that by adding an entry in DNS server will route traffic to my cluster when accessed from outside of the cluster(external).
But without DNS entry in the server/cloud, I need to test the Ingress configuration locally by adding an entry to /etc/hosts or something like.

I found in a baremetal tutorial, adding the HA Proxy IP to /etc/hosts file redirects traffic to kubernetes cluster. Just like that, added the "ip_of_k8_cluster test.domain.com" to /etc/hosts the tried to access like "curl http://test.domain.com/" but the URL is not reachable.

How to verify(internal) the hostname in the Ingress resource without having actual DNS entry for host. I want to make sure my Ingress resource is perfectly working then I can request my company admin to add the name in DNS.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP which you have to add to `/etc/hosts` is not the IP of the Kubernetes-Cluster, it must be the *External-IP* of the *Ingress-Service*.

And the `port` and `targetPort` of the *Ingress-Service* must be also correct (in your case `port` to `80` and `targetPort` to the one on which your Ingress Service listens).

Comment: i can only use the service type as LoadBalancer in case of testing the ingress locally. so adding the Service External IP will route traffic directly to service and not to Ingress, so how the ingress is tested locally.

Comment: No I mean that you have to use the Service-IP of the *Ingress* Pod and you can also use *LoadBalancer* instead of *External-IP* it does not matter in this case.

Comment: @arunp does it work? If it is so please mark it as Answer.

Comment: When Ingress used, the obvious service type will be NodePort or ClusterIP and these service types does not have the external IP. in this case, only LoadBalancer provides ExternalIP. I had to use the IP from kubectl get ing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl` with the `--resolve` flag, example;

```
host=test.domain.com
adr=<your-external-or-loadbalancer-ip-for-the-nginx-service>
curl -D - --resolv $host:80:$adr http://$host/
```

Or with https;

```
curl -D - --resolv $host:443:$adr --insecure https://$host/
```

Comment: thanks @lgekman. Nice to know curl has the option to resolve ip. this also the accepted answer.